# undertanding javascript pagination math problem

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am trying to understand how to approach math problems such as the following excerpt, which was demonstrated in a pagination section of a tutorial I was following.

```
const renderResults = (arrayOfItems, pageNum = 1, resultsPerPage = 10) => {
  const start = (pageNum - 1) * resultsPerPage;
  const end   = pageNum * resultsPerPage;
  arrayOfItems.splice(start, end).forEach(renderToScreenFunction);
};
```

In the tutorial this solution was just typed out and not explained, which got me thinking, had I not seen the solution, I would not have been able to think of it in such a way.

I understood the goal of the problem, and how splice works to break the array into parts. But it was not obvious to me how to obtain the start and end values for using the splice method on an array of of indefinite length. How should have I gone about thinking to solve this problem?

Please understand, I am learning programming in my spare time and what might seem simple to most, I have always been afraid and struggle with math and I am posting this question in hopes to get better.

I would really appreciate if anyone could explain how does one go about solving such problems in theory. And what area of mathematics/programming should I study to get better at such problems. Any pointers would be a huge help. Many thanks.

Comment: This seems less a question about mathematics and more a question on creativity. `How should have I gone about thinking to solve this problem?` When I'm struggling with a problem, I'll try to break it into a smaller problem. Using your example, the "smaller" problem could be "How can I show (just) the first page?", after mentally finding a solution to that, next would be "just the second page?" Putting it back into maths terms, those answers are solutions for page `n` and page `n + 1`, and so all pages

Comment: @Sam, I personally like your question, but I don't believe that it is an appropriate question for stackoverflow. I've voted to close this question, but if edited to be a clear and specific programming questions I would reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so what you're starting with is

- a list of things to display that's, well, it's as long as it is.
- a page number, such that the first page is page 1
- a page size (number of items per page)

So to know which elements in the list to show, you need to think about what the page number and page size say about how many elements you have to *skip*.  If you're on page 1, you don't need to skip any elements. What if you're on page 5?

Well, the first page skips nothing. The second page will have to skip the number of elements per page. The *third* page will have to skip *twice* the number of elements per page, and so on. We can generalize that and see that for page *p*, you need to skip *p - 1* times the number of elements per page. Thus for page 5 you need to skip 4 times the number of elements per page.

To show that page after skipping over the previous pages is easy: just show the next elements-per-page elements.

Note that there are two details that the code you posted does not appear to address. These details are:

1. What if the actual length of the list is not evenly divisible by the page size?
2. What if a page far beyond the actual length of the list is requested?

For the first detail, you just need to test for that situation *after* you've figured out how far to skip forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your function has an error, in the Splice method

```
  arrayOfItems.splice(start, end).forEach(renderToScreenFunction);
```

> The second argument must be the length to extract, not the final
>   index. You don't need to calculate the `end` index, but use the
>   `resultsPerPage` instead.

I've rewrite the code without errors, removing the function wrapper for better understanding, and adding some comments...

```js
// set the initial variables
const arrayOfItems =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'];
const pageNum = 2;
const resultsPerPage = 5;

// calculate start index
const start = (pageNum - 1) * resultsPerPage; // (2-1)*5=5

// generate a new array with elements from arrayOfItems from index 5 to 10
const itemsToShow = arrayOfItems.splice(start, resultsPerPage) ; 

// done! output the results iterating the resulting array
itemsToShow.forEach( x=> console.log(x) )
```

Code explanation :

- Sets the initial parameters
- Calculate the `start index` of the array, corresponding to the page you try to get. ( `(pageNum - 1) * resultsPerPage` )
- Generates a new array, extracting `resultsPerPage` items from `arrayOfItems` , starting in the  `start` index (empty array is returned if the page does not exist)
- Iterates the generated array (`itemsToShow`) to output the results.

The best way to understand code, is sometimes try to run it and observe the behavior and results.